# Sort Visual Studio .settings-file

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt

I'm looking for a way to sort the .settings xml-file created by Visual Studio.
The setting-elements should be sorted by the value of the Value element.

I'm guessing it's an easy job for xslt, but for me it.. a long yak shaving.

Answer (score 0):

It's not xslt, just quick and dirty C#

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = args[0];

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings";

        XElement settingsElement = xDoc.Root.Element(xmlns + "Settings");

        var orderedSettingElements = settingsElement.Elements(xmlns + "Setting").OrderBy(element => element.Element(xmlns + "Value").Value).ToArray();

        settingsElement.RemoveAll();

        foreach (XElement settingElement in orderedSettingElements)
        {
            settingsElement.Add(settingElement);
        }

        xDoc.Save(path);
    }
}
```